# Highstock chart not displaying with inital zero value with percent option

Tags: highcharts

Creating a chart which will have inital zero values in its series and have the compare option on but this will not display a chart.

```
$(function () {
 $('#container').highcharts({
  plotOptions: {
            series: {
                compare: 'percent'
            }
        },

    series: [{
        name: 'Sample',
        data: [0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
    }]
 });
});
```

[Inital Value Zero jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/briask/d6cuq90x/1/)

If I change the initial value to non-zero then the chart will display

```
series: [{
        name: 'Sample',
        data: [1, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
```

[Initial Value Non Zero jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/briask/d6cuq90x/)

Having a zero value does cause issues for the percent compare but it still should be able to display the chart. Any ideas other than removing the valid initial zero value or the percent compare??

Comment: How would you represent zero-value in percentage scale? I mean, what value should be set for the next point? For example `[1, 10, 100]` will display as: `[0%, 100%, 1000%]`, but with `[0, 10, 100]` it will be `[0%, Infinity%, Infinity%]` ? Anyway, take part in [this discussion](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/951).

Comment: In my usage, the data series will only have zeroes in the first number of values in the series, so ideally the chart would ignore the initial zeroes and the resultant infinity calculation. Then once the chart has valid percentages the chart would be presented. So for your example [0, 10, 100] becomes [0%, 900%], ignoring the 0 to 10 percent.

Comment: Feel free to add your comment in the github ticket. In my opinion, you can simply remove first point from the data array for now (`data.splice(0, 1)`).

Comment: That is a workaround but it is not a solution as the zero value is a valid data point. I have updated the Github issue with a comment and noted that in the case of multiple series being plotted, the data series with no issues should at least be plotted.

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant - for now you can remove first point, until ticket will be resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was an existing issue in HighCharts/HighStock [Graph disappear when comparing (percent) and series start with 0](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/951) which has now been resolved & committed by Torstein. Many thanks to Pawel for pointing out the existing issue.